# Why my java socket can't end itself?

Tags: java, sockets, io

Here is my code snippet:

```
            BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(
                    server.getInputStream());
            LittleEndianDataInputStream ledis = new LittleEndianDataInputStream(
                    in);

            byte[] contents = new byte[1024];

            System.out.println("45");
            int bytesRead = 0;
            String s;
            while ((bytesRead = ledis.read(contents)) > 0) {
                System.out.println(bytesRead);
                s = new String(contents, 0, bytesRead);
                System.out.print(s);
            }

            System.out.println("53");
```

After my client send the message to the socket, and the programme successfully print the result, but I can't print the `53`, until I stop the client socket's connection. What should I do to deal with it? My client is an async socket. Thanks.

Comment: call `flush()` on the stream

Answer (score 1):

Your while-loop ends, when it gets an EOF and an EOF is sent from the writing side, whenever you either close the socket or - more graceful - shutdown the output.
So, in your case, your while-loop will end, when the sending side calls `socket.shutdownOutput()`. This closes just the output stream and puts an EOF at the end of the data.

I'm pretty sure this was discussed before, unfortunately I cannot find the question any more to just link. From the top of my head, the writing side should run the following code to close the connection gracefully:

```
// lets say the output stream is buffered, is namend bos and was created like this:
BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

// Then the closing sequence should be
bos.flush();
socket.shutdownOutput(); // This will send the EOF to the reading side

// And on the reading side at the end of your code you can close the socket after getting the EOF
....
            while ((bytesRead = ledis.read(contents)) > 0) {
            System.out.println(bytesRead);
            s = new String(contents, 0, bytesRead);
            System.out.print(s);
        }

        System.out.println("53");
        server.close; // <- After EOF was received, so no Exception will be thrown
```